# Trying to calculate value for row with previous row one

Tags: python, pandas

I've got one DataFrame, and im working on it with Pandas.
Im trying to create a new column names values2, and the values are:
Something like this:

```
   value value2
a    1     1
b    2     y = 2 + x
c    3     z = y + 3
```

I have no idea how to do it, i've tried several ways without any success.

Comment: What is `x` here?

Comment: `i've tried severeal ways without any sucess.`

Can you please post what you have tried and the error message(s) / erroneous result(s) you are getting, please?

Comment: Hi, it would be way better if you post what you have tried (your "tentativas") and what is wrong with them. Don't be afraid of criticism, feedback here tends to sound harsh if you are new to this site but (almost) everyone is trying to help. :-)

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `.cumsum()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

setup the data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"value1": tuple(range(1, 4))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=tuple("abc"))
```

`df` is now

```
   value1
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

and then:

```
df["value2"] = df.cumsum()
```

which gives

```
   value1  value2
a       1       1
b       2       3
c       3       6
```